# Got error when loading Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a weird error when loading angularjs.  I tried to search in the web but nothing found.  Do you know what does that mean?

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token ',' is an unexpected token at column 5 of the expression ['ar', 'Arabic'),
...
('zh-tw', 'Traditional Chinese'].
at Error (unknown source)
at throwError (http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/js/libs/angularjs/angular-1.0.0rc11.js:5845:11)
at parser (http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/js/libs/angularjs/angular-1.0.0rc11.js:5839:5)
at http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/js/libs/angularjs/angular-1.0.0rc11.js:6402:29
at http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/js/libs/angularjs/angular-1.0.0rc11.js:4822:27
at addTextInterpolateDirective (http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/js/libs/angularjs/angular-1.0.0rc11.js:4406:27)
at collectDirectives (http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/js/libs/angularjs/angular-1.0.0rc11.js:3908:11)
at compileNodes (http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/js/libs/angularjs/angular-1.0.0rc11.js:3798:21)
at compileNodes (http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/js/libs/angularjs/angular-1.0.0rc11.js:3806:14)
at compileNodes (http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/js/libs/angularjs/angular-1.0.0rc11.js:3806:14) angular-1.0.0rc11.js:5541
$get
```

Comment: Did you modify the JS file after downloading it? What you're getting is a parser error, due to incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of trial and error, finally found out what happens here.  Think it worths sharing with you guys so that you will not waste time when facing the same issue.

The problem is that I have used bad start (`((`) and end (`))`) symbols when configuring the `interpolateProvider`.  After changing the start and end symbols to another ones, then the error is gone.